# The tomcat 9 was normal at first, but now it is always starting to fail, how to solve it?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

```
[2017-06-09 08:58:49,618] Artifact jt-manage-web:war exploded: Server is not 
 connected. Deploy is not available.
 Using CATALINA_BASE:   
 "C:\Users\Administrator\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_jt-parent"
  Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\program\tomcat9.0"
  Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\program\tomcat9.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "D:\program\jdk\jdk1.7.0_15"
  Using CLASSPATH:
```

"D:\program\tomcat9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\program\tomcat9.0\bin\tomcat-
    [image]juli.jar"
Disconnected from server

Comment: The message you see indicates that IDE is waiting for the server to start in order to perform deployment. It's not an error. You need to figure out why the server fails to start. See if it works from the command line outside of IntelliJ IDEA, try a new default Tomcat installation without any changes to the configuration, try using Java 8 to run it instead of this ancient Java 7 build you have that can be blocked by an antivirus.

Comment: OK, it can start in  command line.

Comment: Good to know, now do the rest of the things described. Also check the server logs in the CATALINA_BASE/logs directory.

Comment: when jdk1.8, it success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue was caused by the ancient Java 7 build and running on Java 8 has fixed it.

According to [this page](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), Tomcat 9 requires Java 8 or later to run.

Answer (score 0):

According to the above tips, I tested it many times, 
when tomcat's jdk is 1.8, it success,
when tomcat's jdk is 1.7, it failed.
Looks like it's really tomcat's jdk problem.